# fabricjs 1.7.3 tsd for angularJs + TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, fabricjs

I'm looking for the tsd for the last version of fabricjs (1.7.3), but i can only find tsd for 1.5 (here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fabric/index.d.ts)

I need to use some stuf like in this example http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing
But i'm not able to do

```
...
private canvas : fabric.ICanvas;
...
public constructor()
 this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        this.canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
        this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric['PencilBrush'](this.canvas);
...
```

It says that freeDrawingBrush doesn't exist on type ICanvas (but i'm very new to fabricjs so maybe i'm doing something wrong?)
Where can i find it or is there any easy way to generate it?
Thx